# Buttons displaying both times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, axios

The issue is lying in my Sean Connery and Roger Moore list of movies buttons. When I click on Sean Connery List of Movies, it displays Connery movies on Roger Moore's list too, and vice versa.

**Prettier 2.7.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAgCU4BDMGAGn2HwFcBnOAZRhPnwF98AzHCdfAB0QOUuWEBuQVAzY8+ejACeAGzgATHnwHDFqjQFpIWaAhj1J02bgIkAHqgj0t-ISHuOLIKVGmQoivgAQrQwMND4ALwKymrqAHQARqHhUAAG0vj4iWQA1gDmfLRQ6kYQKrhI2Sp5PlmQFThVAO4AFqjwdTzQMAb0qABecFUATAAMmHZdmCTq6qhQ+VUAjBN2+ABsa12JuOpwOAY4s6gMVQCsk13oJDj5Cytr+NuZ+GC0OPSV+NgL8Dg+NI+aTcYrkRxQYIpaAAYRUqDAuQAFABKaivfyBADaDAO9CojBgAFVGJ8ALpROiMFhsOCorqYgjcOAwMCtAAibBIlKRykwcDRkQAfOjIVl8B4nK9xfh4vkWUjpTK3K0wph6EgAPSawZQbgAR3oAE4RlAAMzxOB2ODveAGEiYVDxBgGZpwRQGZbxEg3AbQEjNejxYya-YAN01DtQmrDI016AgYdQ7uESqyKLTspgrQQSKRono2ACAqiIuAmfq0C+aniFXy+fdRcY8XUXIzYuVbyrBBumH56gAgjhjkpKQWm3AW1yK+L4r3FR3O+KkR04OhBUKZ53V+gsXy4BSAD6HrfK3lKflRSLRYTzUTkXBefAAMmf+B3LdQ9-CODRx9PMrnpe143iAMAdGoAD6XyLMIL5vh+4EwFBMH5H+J6Lkuy77leoEJkmcCQUopA4HBr7vvA6BzomyZESR7ZYemp7xNwqAqP8ebFKg+q0HAABqJAqBudAyDx-GCSiXSdoSJJ4kiNB7heB5VEOI4sdoSJYvE2lQHAzT4EwCq9v2qkkEoKJkmiHCSTO2pdgE5STnWSL4cm9AMcq1ldBwDLdvgWKue6BIsgAsjR7oUtEuI0vA9IYn5zKsq0YUEZyrA8lAPolsKoqdpKFiYbK8owAuWHCKqMDqlqOoDHqhomualrWracD2o6zr0K67q9F6PokH6mWBsG-ChnAEZRjGcaBV4mYovE2a5uOVZwKWuVLpijm1hA9ZLcWU6sB50mheF9ANoWy37SQLFsRxO6rR+uwlJBZA-rh+CZegApzg6K6UfdlHUQRkFIWoKI2YVlYOTWznCAAEnAKgVPgADquAqOowiHcqG3Q9tiogPDiMQCjaMYyAWMynZONOXjFOcFjPnSK8ogwB8kKleKAA88xhpuhXc6gvMzpzrQjEKQTQJoaUkDkjCc5qot81hIvnErjFwgiuT4BEC3ZNCAT4OEChwCtuvwoEEDcBKiOGzm2SS-ggUAOQFYx+B3jaP74vbJQSg+nxUKIagkIw+DEbcVAkL7IMrahrtLvLrSq0zEP4JzIRhBEsLwoikTAKiq2JWy0v4496jPf7mMcOLDsDv79DyxnqRq52wC4p88H4Bzyu0CoLeMW3pL0AA-EkksVz+o-zki7dUAs+x2MJ3du2n8L4LkcBKHn89WtXAHKpz3KtKI3CROVaoatquoGsapoWlaNqhK1UYdV1Hq9b6-pDSG4aRo6k3xhOsIfuK9xSDwOBwfeMp5YkBAYxeW8I4GdjBpA1OWR5a9yQfgFEqDOzyx5nAgWQtU7p31trKAGtc752EkXDkXJ8Ye3rlXIU7Ivye0fI3fWWDwEd3IsvPBmD948JHp+b8j4p4-SRIwn8S8oGr1QOvTeedpG4GrsAFROAOAINQFgmUKDTwYL7jOHBmZ8GC0IQQ4WTcs4UJzrkPOBccq0JLsIGO0FoD5GYUwDxDdNTWKgNw9uzg+EGMEWgsBQTR5uNQhIzAeZokeNkeE6Ba8N5b2AAkxYajMn5C0ZqRB+99HhMMVgkx-NQzmNMZYkh-jyGUPsdQwuLJi70OEIFOitxmEpWTPgAAmiRThmcAkzmEZ3fhB8wmgOEVPcKHScCxLzO08Ov5VrjOVqkpRwAlkkTUds24eSCnJOwWUt2JTjG4IPhU4heDqnK1qdnTWDiaHNOSuFFxIBDJR3wDCaAukcBKC8aQSEPyoB-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-NNaUAhwMLpDQGgj2iB4mwz966f1IF7f+xg6BUCTunfBkA-RFgQagzBkTf6ZOsESDhvDrRkAjFzVOkgbFx0-PQMJkA7pzhHtxAAFRlmx0TMmwy8QAJIlDMEwMAWGC0DhKCwfQsHGAcA4EAA)

```bash
--parser babel
```

**Input:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function ButtonClick() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        const mappedArray = response.data
          .map(
            (item) =>
              item[type] ||
              (type === "directors" && item.director) ||
              (type === "title_song" && item.title_song) ||
              (type === "movie_year" && item.movie_year)
          )
          .filter((uniqueVal) => uniqueVal);
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from([...new Set(mappedArray)]) });
        // console.log(movies)
      });
  };
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState();
  const fetchMovieData = (name) => {
      axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      ).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setMovies(response.data.filter(item => item.bond_actor === name).map(item => item.movie_title));
        console.log("Hello World")
        console.log("Hello World")
        // console.log()
      })
    };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>
          Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's
          directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <a href="https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies">
                  {user}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((director) => (
              <li key={director}>{director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((title_song) => (
              <li key={title_song}>{title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((movie_year) => (
              <li key={movie_year}>{movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Sean Connery")}>Sean Connery's List of Movies</Button>
        {movies && (
          // console.log(movies),
          <ul>
            {movies?.map((movie) => (
            // console.log(movie),
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          
        )
        }
        
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Roger Moore")}>Roger Moore List of Movies</Button>
        {movies && (
          <ul>
            {movies?.map((movie) => (
              // console.log(moviesR),
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```

I'd assume the issue is that both buttons are using the same state, but since the names have spaces, I don't know how to create different states for the two buttons. If I get some assistance on this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function ButtonClick() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        const mappedArray = response.data
          .map(
            (item) =>
              item[type] ||
              (type === "directors" && item.director) ||
              (type === "title_song" && item.title_song) ||
              (type === "movie_year" && item.movie_year)
          )
          .filter((uniqueVal) => uniqueVal);
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from([...new Set(mappedArray)]) });
        // console.log(movies)
      });
  };
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});
  const fetchMovieData = (name) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setMovies({
          [name]: response.data
            .filter((item) => item.bond_actor === name)
            .map((item) => item.movie_title)
        });
        console.log("Hello World");
        console.log("Hello World");
        // console.log()
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>
          Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's
          directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <a href="https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies">
                  {user}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((director) => (
              <li key={director}>{director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((title_song) => (
              <li key={title_song}>{title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((movie_year) => (
              <li key={movie_year}>{movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Sean Connery")}>
          Sean Connery's List of Movies
        </Button>
        {movies && (
          // console.log(movies),
          <ul>
            {movies?.["Sean Connery"]?.map((movie) => (
              // console.log(movie),
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Roger Moore")}>
          Roger Moore List of Movies
        </Button>
        {movies && (
          <ul>
            {movies?.["Roger Moore"]?.map((movie) => (
              // console.log(moviesR),
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```

Comment: I like the use of computed keys here, but is your intention to only show   one actor's movies at a time? `fetchMovieData` passes a single-keyed object to `setMovies` in your example.

Comment: According to the author's previous question, I thought, his intention is to show one at a time.

Comment: One of the author's problems is that either button's click action causes the same actor's movies to be displayed on both lists at the same time. The author did not indicate that they would not want to render both actors' lists at once. What do you think, @prashant-potluri?

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this is to take a reducer approach:

```
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});
  const fetchMovieData = (name) => {
      axios
      .get(
        "..."
      ).then(response => {
        ...
        const newMoviesState = {...movies};
        newMoviesState[name] = response.data.filter(item => item.bond_actor === name).map(item => item.movie_title)
        setMovies(newMoviesState);
        ...
      })
    };
```

Then, in your JSX for the buttons and lists:

```
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Sean Connery")}>Sean Connery's List of Movies</Button>
        {movies["Sean Connery"]?.length && (
          ...
          <ul>
            {movies["Sean Connery"].map((movie) => (
              ...
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          
        )
        }
        
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so because you are using single state, `movies` to show movies under both sections.

```
<ul>
        {movies?.map((movie) => (
          // console.log(moviesR),
          <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
        ))}
 </ul>
```

This is common to both sections, and this only checks whether movies have any value or not.

This issue can be solved by creating different states for different movie collections.

Answer (score 0):

found a simple way to do it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function ButtonClick() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        const mappedArray = response.data
          .map(
            (item) =>
              item[type] ||
              (type === "directors" && item.director) ||
              (type === "title_song" && item.title_song) ||
              (type === "movie_year" && item.movie_year)
          )
          .filter((uniqueVal) => uniqueVal);
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from([...new Set(mappedArray)]) });
        // console.log(movies)
      });
  };
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({sean:[], roger: []});

  const fetchMovieData = (name, key) => {
      axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      ).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setMovies({...movies,[key]:response.data.filter(item => item.bond_actor === name).map(item => item.movie_title)});
        console.log("Hello World")
        console.log("Hello World")
        console.log(movies)
      })
    };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>
          Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's
          directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <a href="https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies">
                  {user}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((director) => (
              <li key={director}>{director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((title_song) => (
              <li key={title_song}>{title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((movie_year) => (
              <li key={movie_year}>{movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Sean Connery", "sean")}>Sean Connery's List of Movies</Button>
        {movies && movies.sean && (
          // console.log(movies),
          <ul>
            {movies?.sean?.map((movie) => (
            // console.log(movie),
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          
        )
        }
        
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchMovieData("Roger Moore", "roger")}>Roger Moore List of Movies</Button>
        {movies && movies.roger && (
          <ul>
            {movies?.roger?.map((movie) => (
              // console.log(moviesR),
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```

you can simply pass a key and make sub arrays for each actor
if u can use key map object it will be less confusing.

ex:

```
const actors = {
  sean: "Sean Connery",
  roger: "Roger Moore"
}
```

Comment: The conditional rendering logic here will sometimes cause renders of unnecessary empty `ul`'s: ```{movies && (
          <ul>```

Comment: Yeah it must be ```{movies && movies.<actor_movies_key> && ( <ul>```